# Pytest fixture returning multiples

Tags: python, pytest

Is it possible to have a fixture that returns a dictionary and dataframe?

```
import somefile
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def setup():
    dictionary, dataframe = somefile.get_Di_And_Df()
    return(dictionary, dataframe)

def test_check(setup):
    assert dictionary['movie']['action'] == 'Avengers'
    assert dataframe.shape[0] == 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value (or yield value) of the fixture is literally the object injected as a function argument during test execution:

```
def test_check(setup):
    dictionary, dataframe = setup
    assert dictionary['movie']['action'] == 'Avengers'
    assert dataframe.shape[0] == 5
```

Answer (score 4):

The most readable way is to return a `namedtuple` in the fixture:

```
from collections import namedtuple

import somefile
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def setup():
    dictionary, dataframe = somefile.get_Di_And_Df()
    return namedtuple("Setup", "dictionary dataframe")(dictionary, dataframe)


def test_check(setup):
    assert setup.dictionary['movie']['action'] == 'Avengers'
    assert setup.dataframe.shape[0] == 5
```

Answer (score 0):

you could mock the called method

```
@patch("somefile.get_Di_And_Df", MagicMock=(return_value=(dictionary, dataframe)))
def test_check():
  _dict, _df = somefile.get_Di_And_Df()
  assert _dict['movie']['action'] == 'Avengers'
  assert _df.shape[0] == 5
```